# Python Regular Expression (from Quick Book)

Tags: python, regex

I have recently learned a bit about Python re module from "Python Quick Book".

I have tried to test a code from the book. besides there is no error in my code, it is not recognizing the pattern of data givn in the file.

```
    import re
regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<last>[-a-zA-Z]+)"
                    r"(?P<first>[-a-zA-Z]+)"
                    r" ( (?P<middle> ([-a-zA-Z]+)))?"
                    r": (?P<phone> (\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)"
                    )
file = open ('dir.txt', 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    result = regexp.search(line)
    if result == None:
        print ("Oops, I don't think this is a record")
    else:
        lastname = result.group('last')
        firstname = result.group('first')
        middlename = result.group('middle')
        if middlename == None:
            middlename = ''
        phonenumber = result.group('phone')
        print ('Name:', firstname, middlename, lastname, ' Number: ',phonenumber)
file.close()
```

and here is the data given in my textfile.

```
Khan, Ahmed Ali : 800-123-4567
Malik, Asif Ali : 800-123-7844
Shaikh, Muhammad Sharafat: 300-123-4444
Shah, Farhat Abbas : 321-822-2977
Adam, Khalid Ahmed : 000-124-5454
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, but if this code is from the book, get another book. There are at least three explicit bad practices in this program (not using `with` for I/O, explicitly calling `readlines`, and `== None`).

Comment: Thank you for valuable info. I shall be thankful if anyone may also check the code.

Answer (score 5):

The regexp is wrong for the input data

To fix it, take the following approach

drop into the python immediate evalution and import re

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
```

define a string as one of the input lines

```
>>> str="Khan, Ahmed Ali : 800-123-4567"
```

apply the regexp patterns a bit at a time to see what fails

```
>>> regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<last>[-a-zA-Z]+)")
>>> result=regexp.search(str)
>>> print result.group('last')
Khan
```

so the first one works, try the first two

```
>>> regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<last>[-a-zA-Z]+)"
...                     r"(?P<first>[-a-zA-Z]+)")
>>> result=regexp.search(str)
>>> print result.group('last')
Kha
>>> print result.group('first')
n
```

Oh dear!  Looking carefully, the str has a comma and space after Khan, and  so let's fix that

```
>>> regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<last>[-a-zA-Z]+),\s+"
... r"(?P<first>[-a-zA-Z]+)")
>>> result=regexp.search(str)
>>> print result.group('last')
Khan
>>> print result.group('first')
Ahmed
>>>
```

Just adjust the regexps like this interactively until it works on one input string.  Then copy the working regexps back to your program

Comment: Thank you very much Vorsprung!  for the breakup of process. This will definitely help me to understand the overall process thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code requires two spaces before the middle name:

```
r" ( (?P<middle> ([-a-zA-Z]+)))?"
# ^ ^
```

Instead, you should use the `\s` character class and `*` or `+` quantifiers. Also, explictly closing files, using `re.search` when you really want `re.match`, and comparing to `None` with `==` are all bad practices. Instead, write your code like this:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile(r"(?P<last>[-a-zA-Z]+), "
                    r"(?P<first>[-a-zA-Z]+)"
                    r"(\s+(?P<middle>[-a-zA-Z]+))?\s*"
                    r":\s*(?P<phone>(\d{3}-)?\d{3}-\d{4})$"
                    )
with open('dir.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regexp.match(line)
        if result is None:
            print ("Oops, I don't think this is a record")
            continue
        lastname = result.group('last')
        firstname = result.group('first')
        middlename = result.group('middle')
        if middlename is None:
            middlename = ''
        phonenumber = result.group('phone')
        print ('Name:', firstname, middlename, lastname, ' Number: ',phonenumber)
```

Comment: Also, `(\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d` should be rewritten as `\d{3}?\d{3}-\d{4}`. Much more readable and less error-prone. This book is obviously really bad what you are having there.

Comment: Thank you phihag! This is code is working I will just go through all its components.

Comment: Thank you Peter! will you please suggest any other smart book on the subject.

Comment: @pleasureinblues [Head First Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920003434.do) and [Dive into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/) are two options. Since both are available for free online, just have a look inside and pick whichever one you find better.

Comment: @phihag Thanks again....! You have been very much helpful for me. May God bless you. :)