# Regular expression using python is not working

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
import re
sum=0
file = open("pro.txt").readlines()
for lines in file:
        word= len(re.findall('(^|[^\w\-])able#1(?=([^\w\-]|$))', lines))
        if word>0:
                sum=sum+1
print sum
```

I am counting number of words in text file , but my program also count some words which is not of our need , i use r.e in it , but its not giving me any appropriate help
this is my text file

```
0         6          9     able#1
0         11         34    unable#1
9         12         22    able#1
0         6          9     able#1-able#1
0         11         34    unable#1*able#1
```

I dont want my program to count ,`-able#1 ,able#1-able#1 ,unable#1*able#1` these type of word , i should only count `able#1`

Comment: @nhahtdh but i also have to find the number against that word through this text file

Comment: how about just removing everything after the first occurrence of the hash symbol ?

Comment: why not apply the regex after removing everything past the first occurrence of the '#' symbol (plus one more character maybe)?

Comment: yes , but if i match the word label than i also have to find the number against it like 0 6 9 in the example above

Comment: @nhahtdh sorry i didn't get your point , i have a big dataset in txt file same like i have mention as example

Comment: @Angel: For each line, cut up your data into 4  parts `0`, `6`, `9`, `able#1` (can be done with split, with limit on number of parts), and check the last item to decide to keep the data or not.

Comment: @nhahtdh nice and easy explanation thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `\sable#1\s*$` that requires one whitespace before `able` and allows zero or more whitespace (and nothing else) at the end of line.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\sable#1\s*$')
count = 0
with open("pro.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if regex.search(line):
            count += 1
print count
```

You could also count with `sum()` and a generator expression like this:

```
with open("pro.txt") as file:
    count = sum(1 for line in file if regex.search(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\W]*able#1\W
```

The [^\W]* expression means match zero or more characters that are not non alphanumeric
So it will not care about the "un" in "unable"!

I would write the regexp like this

```
if re.search('\s+[-_]*able#\S*',lines):
```

`\s+` is any non zero amount of whitespace
`\S*` is any amount of whitespace including zero

EDIT: altered for late requirement change to match "_able#" and "-able#"

Comment: You might like to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808943/python-regular-expression-from-quick-book/14809474#14809474 which tries to explain how to debug regexp

Comment: i tried this one , because it also count able#1-able#1 , i want to just count able#1 to -able#1 or _able#1

Comment: i change my r.e , but still a bit problem is remaining , you link was i think not related to my work

Comment: Angel the link is a short answer I wrote on how to effectively test regexps in python immediate evalutation mode, you might find it useful

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in counting complete words, you could do this:

```
re.findall('(?:\W|\A)able#1(?=\W|\Z)', line)
```

The `(?:\W|\A)` will match either the beginning of `line` or something that's not like a word (i.e. `[0-9a-z_]`).

Likewise, `(?=\W|\Z)` is a look-ahead assertion for either the end of `line` or something that's not like a word.